# How can i add error message to API call discord python

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I have been working on a simple api call for my bot and it works just fine but if I enter the wrong input or the api is down the bot simply dose not reply

Any way to get the bot to reply with an error message if the api has an error or 404 for example?

I tried to use an else command but I kept getting errors

My code so far:

```
@client.command()
async def zip(ctx, zip):
    url = ('http://api.zippopotam.us/us/' + zip)
    response = requests.get(url)
    placename = response.json()["places"][0]["place name"]
    lon = response.json()["places"][0]["longitude"]
    state = response.json()["places"][0]["state"]
    lat = response.json()["places"][0]["latitude"]

    embed = discord.Embed(title="Zip location info for " + zip, color=0x00ffff)
    embed.add_field(name="City:", value=f'{placename}', inline=True)
    embed.add_field(name="State:", value=f'{state}', inline=True)
    embed.add_field(name="Latitude:", value=f'{lat}', inline=True)
    embed.add_field(name="Longitude:", value=f'{lon}', inline=True)
    
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`requests.get()` returns a `Response` object with a `status_code` attribute, as shown in the [`requests` documentation](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/).

You can simply check  whether `status_code` is equal to `404`, or whichever specific value you want to check:

```py
response = requests.get(...)
# check if the status_code lies in user error range
if 400 <= response.status_code <= 499:
    # return error here
```